# Cura: How to prevent my 3D printer from auto cooling after prints

Tags: ultimaker-cura, nozzle, cooling, bed, temperature

Is there a setting or G-code, to prevent Ultimaker Cura from setting the nozzle and build plate temperatures to 0? I have looked and have not found anything in the printer beginning/ending G-code, print settings, etc...

**Would this have something to do with it?**
[image: end GCODE]

Comment: Cura will skip emitting the heat-up gcode at the beginning if your custom start gcode contains variable expansions for temperature, but I don't know if there's anything comparable for end gcode. This is actually really annoying. You might need a postprocessing script to fix it.

Comment: Playing with the settings, I can keep the build plate hot, but the hotend still gets reset.

Comment: It is a **fire hazard** to not turn off the hotend after the print.

Answer (score 1):

In CuraEngine's [`FffGcodeWriter::finalize`](https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine/blob/0852f3cd5e909c9ebb459befb499292460da97d4/src/FffGcodeWriter.cpp#L2943-L3011) method, G-code to zero the bed and enclosure temperature is only written if the machine profile defines a heated bed/enclosure, so you could in theory avoid the cooldown by telling Cura your machine doesn't and putting the heatup commands in your custom start gcode instead of letting Cura emit them itself. However it unconditionally zeros all of the hotend temperatures, and does this after emitting your custom end G-code, so you can't even turn the hotend back on from there. The only way to undo Cura's insistence on turning it off is with some sort of postprocessing.

Update: There's actually a way to fix this purely at the configuration/profile level! Set `machine_nozzle_temp_enabled` ("Enable Nozzle Temperature Control") to false (off) and Cura will not emit *any* M104/M109 temperature commands. You can then put whatever temperature commands you do or don't want in your start/end gcode.

Comment: The insistence on turning off the hotend is a fire safety thing.

Comment: @Trish: Yes, but that can be handled better in the firmware or print server (preferably independenly in both, so if either one fails on its own the other works as a fallback) as an inactivity timeout rather than an immediate cooldown (which messes up immediate second print; even if you rapidly re-select "preheat" it's cooled down to 160 or so already).

Comment: It's actually rather odd that Cura doesn't have an option to disable hotend temperature controls entirely, since presumably some people will use it with non-heated extruders for pastes that are viscous but flow at room temperature.

Comment: And... it turns out it does! Updated answer with new info.